# c# get post form data sent from browser by socket sometimes socket closes.why?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I have webserver receive data by async sockets:

```
var e = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            e.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(e_Completed);

 while (true)
                { allDone.Reset();
                    mySocket.AcceptAsync(e);
                    allDone.WaitOne();
                }
```

and the other method:

```
    public void e_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        var socket = (Socket)sender;
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(handleTcpRequest, e.AcceptSocket);
        e.AcceptSocket = null;
        socket.AcceptAsync(e);
    }
```

this is the handleTcpRequest method.in this part I receive data from socket and do operation:

```
public void handleTcpRequest(object state)
{
   string sBuffer = "";
   string BufferTotal = "";
   byte[] secureMessage;
   Byte[] bReceive = new Byte[1024];
   var mySocket = (Socket)state;
            do
            {


                  try
                  {
                    firstBufferRead = mySocket.Receive(bReceive, bReceive.Length, 0);
                  }
                  catch (Exception ex)
                  {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error Occurred (:))) " + ex.Message);
                  }

                sBuffer += Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(bReceive, 0, firstBufferRead);
                BufferTotal += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bReceive, 0, firstBufferRead);
            } while (mySocket.Available != 0);
.
.
.
.
mySocket.Close();
}
```

whats wrong?
sometimes connection resets and closes. this happens when distance is far or post data not multipart. but in multipart happens rarely. more with forms not in multipart.
when and where should I close socket?
when I work with socket in handleTcpRequest method its local. isn't it correct? I can't find the origin of the problem

Comment: You are using async IO, then always waiting for it to complete. This is more complicated and slower than just using the synchronous functions. fyi.

Comment: Your error handling is to just keep going. That's probably wrong. You'll just operate on invalid data. Rather, abort processing.

Comment: no no no.ur wrong. when somebody uploading some file or have a long request, others can send their request. don't get confused about this matter

Comment: so what should I do about handling? will you explain more?

Comment: `Available` is unreliable for most purposes. If data has not yet arrived, but will arrive later, Available might just be zero. You don't even need it. Remove it from your code.

Comment: so when I understand there is something in buffer? for multipart data I can recieve untile have //while (!content.Contains(boundarSeprator + "--")) so what about forms that are not multipart and have contents more than buffer size?

Comment: These are mostly different questions. Ask separately. For this question: Use the return value from Receive to find out how many bytes you actually got. Apply all my suggestions to see if the problem is solved.

Comment: My reputation is low.shall we chat in yahoo or gmail or somewhere else? I dont have reputation for chatting here :((

Comment: We don't need a chat, you need to follow the advice given.

Comment: I can't Understand. which condition should I use instead of  while (mySocket.Available != 0); I use return value for concatenating to sbuffer string or buffertotal string but how to use it instead of while(mySocket.Available != 0) ????

Comment: You don't need any condition. Use a while(true) loop and break when the connection is closed or you receive an error. Read the docs for Receive.

Comment: is that your real solution? I just want to do lots of operations on sBuffer after this while. but when its not complete I cant do that. all the operations will fail

Comment: Then break the loop as soon as you have received enough data. At the moment you break it at an arbitrary point, certainly before enough data is received. You understand now that Available makes no sense, right? It does not tell you how much data is left.

Comment: I dont know how much data is.its come from browser.how should behave that? should I receive this part async too? and wait to receive or its not applicable?

Comment: I don't know. That's not the point of this question. I think I have given you all information required to understand why your connection suddenly closes (you are closing it when you arbitrarily exit the loop).

Comment: I cant Understand when data is finished in all situation in http request? is there any character at the end that could help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to know that you've received everything in a HTTP request is to understand the HTTP request. And to understand a HTTP request you have to choices:

1. Use a complete HTTP server
2. Create a HTTP parser

The reason to why your code fails for multi-part data is probably because the other party sends one part at a time, which means that your code manages to do a `mySocket.Available != 0` before the rest is sent.

If you want to do the latter you have to read the HTTP header (in format `headerName: headervalue`, do note that there are also white space rules that you have to consider). Search for a header named `content-length`, parse it's value as an integer. Then wait for two line feeds in a row (`\r\n\r\n`). Finally start count bytes until you have received the number of bytes that was specified in the `content-length` header.

ohh.. ony more thing.. pray to God that `Transfer-Encoding: Chunked`is not used.

My advice is that you give up on using sockets directly as it's apparent that you don't understand how they work or how to do research on them.

Comment: Hi jgauffin. I've downlaoded your webserver and source long time ago and that as so hard to understand. I'll try it and hope to be in contact together more

Comment: I've added the code `code`  while (!sBuffer.Contains("\r\n\r\n")); `code` but still same error

Comment: C# has a built in class: HttpListener

Comment: no. I dont want to work with httpListener.I want lower level. I use socket and tcpListener

Comment: Why do you want to use something that you don't fully understand? Socket programming is complex, writing a robust protocol parser is even more complex. Doing both with no knowledge will only lead to a very fragile solution.

Comment: what should I do? I get content length in first receive from header. how should receive and calculate exact length of content? after first index of "\r\n\r\n" content starts? is that true? start counting after first index of "\r\n\r\n"?

Answer (score 0):

If response has a header of Connection: Close, then the socket closes automatically.